# Unable to install Ubik load pack using Maven

Tags: maven, jmeter, continuous-integration, jmeter-maven-plugin, ubikloadpack

When I run mvn clean install I get this:

> [WARNING] The POM for com.ubikingenierie.ubikloadpack.gwt:ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2:jar:4.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.edgenius:geniuswiki-gwtserver:jar:3.23 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.edgenius:geniuswiki-serpol:jar:3.23 is missing, no dependency information available
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.10.1:jmeter (jmeter-tests) on project my-app: Execution jmeter-tests of goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.10.1:jmeter failed: Plugin com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.10.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.ubikingenierie.ubikloadpack.gwt:ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2:jar:4.1.0, com.edgenius:geniuswiki-gwtserver:jar:3.23, com.edgenius:geniuswiki-serpol:jar:3.23: Failure to find com.ubikingenierie.ubikloadpack.gwt:ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2:jar:4.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>my-app</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <overrideRootLogLevel>INFO</overrideRootLogLevel>
               <suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>
               <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                  <phase>verify</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>jmeter</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <propertiesJMeter>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>false</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData>false</jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.url>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.url>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders>
                        <ULP.gwt.licensepath>/data/ubik/ulp/licenses/trials/ubikloadpack/ubik-gwt-plugin.license</ULP.gwt.licensepath>
                     </propertiesJMeter>
                     <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>${testFile}</jMeterTestFile>
                     </testFilesIncluded>
                     <jmeterPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                           <groupId>com.ubikingenierie.ubikloadpack.gwt</groupId>
                           <artifactId>ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                     </jmeterPlugins>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.ubikingenierie.ubikloadpack.gwt</groupId>
                  <artifactId>ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2</artifactId>
                  <version>4.1.0</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                  <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                  <version>2.7.0</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.edgenius</groupId>
                  <artifactId>geniuswiki-gwtserver</artifactId>
                  <version>3.23</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.edgenius</groupId>
                  <artifactId>geniuswiki-serpol</artifactId>
                  <version>3.23</version>
               </dependency>               
            </dependencies>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue here is that you didn't install in Maven repository the following dependencies:

- com.ubikingenierie.ubikloadpack.gwt:ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2:jar:4.1.0
- com.edgenius:geniuswiki-gwtserver:jar:3.23
- com.edgenius:geniuswiki-serpol:jar:3.23

So you need for each of those (which are not publicly available on Maven Repositories):

> mvn install:install file ....

As per:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html

For example for **ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2-4.1.0.jar** :

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2.jar -DgroupId=com.ubikingenierie.ubikloadpack.gwt -DartifactId=ubik-jmeter-gwt-plugin-above2 -Dversion=4.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

I let you guess the other ones, make sure you modify for each one:
- file
- groupId
- artifactId
- version

You can read a full explanation on this here:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/integrate-load-testing-in-build-process-with-jmeter-ubikloadpack-maven/

Besides, last version of GWT Plugin is 4.2.2, contact support to get an updated version.

Comment: Thank you Ubik. Are these jars open source?